# Does vec[i][j] translates to *(vec + i + j)?

Tags: c++

for example we can refer to a 1d array's element with two ways:

`vec[i]` or `*(vec + i)`

how `vec[i][j]` translates for a 2d array?

Comment: What is the type of `vec`?

Comment: Obviously not, because ```(vec 0 + 1)``` would be equal to ```(vec 1 + 0)``` which are not the same elements

Comment: asuming vec is an array ! it will be   `*(*(vec+i)+j)` which is the same as `*(vec[i]+j)`

Comment: vector<T> vec = new vector<vector<T>>(width, vector<T>(height));

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A logical approach - if `a[x]` is syntatic sugar for `*(a + x)`, then let's unroll the entire expression:

```
vec[i][j]
(*(vec + i))[j]
*((*(vec + i)) + j)
```

Strip a pair of parens and we get:

```
*(*(vec + i) + j)
```

So `vec[i][j]` isn't equal to `*(vec + i + j)`, but `*(*(vec + i) + j)`. There are two dereferences, because of two operator applications. The first expression (as there is only one dereference) translates to `vec[i + j]`.

A slight note: as you're using vector, these two procedures compile to the same assembly (meaning they are equivalent; I used ::iterator instead of plain vector for sake of readability / simplicity):

```
char fn(vector<vector<char>::iterator>::iterator vec, char i, char j) {
    return vec[i][j];
}

char fn2(vector<vector<char>::iterator>::iterator vec, char i, char j) {
    return *(*(vec + i) + j);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

No, `vec[i][j]` is not same as `*(vec + i + j)`; which is `vec[i + j]` in fact.

For [built-in subscript operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_member_access#Built-in_subscript_operator),

> The built-in subscript expression `E1[E2]` is exactly identical to the expression `*(E1 + E2)`

Then `vec[i]` is identical to `*(vec + i)`; `vec[i][j]` is identical to `*(vec[i] + j)` and then `*(*(vec + i) + j)`.

Answer (score -1):

### The right answer

After reading the comment which states that `vec` is actually **not** an array, but a `std::vector<std::vector<T>>`, the below answer is incorrect.

The correct answer would thus be: It's not the same, and there is no strict correlation as both vectors allocate and **re**-allocate their elements independently. So, what happens is that you look up the `i`th `vector` in `vec`, and then ask for the `j`th element there (which is located at `data() + i`, but you do not know where `data()` may be, it's unrelated to the other, surrounding `vector`'s storage).

### The wrong answer

Funnily, the standard writers seemed to have realized how confusing their writing is as the standard contains a `Note:` [section](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.array#7) with an explicit example which addresses your very question:

> [ Note: A consistent rule is followed for multidimensional arrays. If E is an n-dimensional array of rank i×j×⋯×k, then E appearing in an expression that is subject to the array-to-pointer conversion is converted to a pointer to an (n−1)-dimensional array with rank j×⋯×k. If the * operator, either explicitly or implicitly as a result of subscripting, is applied to this pointer, the result is the pointed-to (n−1)-dimensional array, which itself is immediately converted into a pointer. [ Example: Consider
>
> int x[3][5];
>
> Here x is a 3×5 array of integers. When x appears in an expression, it is converted to a pointer to (the first of three) five-membered arrays of integers. In the expression x[i] which is equivalent to *(x+i), x is first converted to a pointer as described; then x+i is converted to the type of x, which involves multiplying i by the length of the object to which the pointer points, namely five integer objects. The results are added and indirection applied to yield an array (of five integers), which in turn is converted to a pointer to the first of the integers. If there is another subscript the same argument applies again; this time the result is an integer.  — end example ]  — end note ]

So, in short, `vec[i][j]` equals `(vec + i )[j]` equals `*(*(vec + i) + j)`. Note how the rank ("size") of the array matters if you look at the address. Because not only is the size of the underlying type (let's call that `T`) being multiplied on the first dereference (that's how accessing an array works!). But also does that happen on the *second* dereference, and here the type happens to be not just one element, but an array of `T`s of some known size.